Yarn install errors related to modules and directories
I am a beginner to react and I came across this error when I checked the version of yarn. It was previously worked but I think I have done something to my directories or perhaps removed some files and and it shows the below error,
yarn -v

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myUserName/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v21.7.3

I also tried to re-install yarn but it shows.
 npm install --global yarn

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/myUserName/.npm/_logs/.     
2024-04-19T06_35_17_001Z-debug-0.log

I have tried uninstalling node and reinstalled, and overwriting files but it did not work.
I would be so grateful if anyone could advise how to fix this error.
Thanks

I suggest you have a read of https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Thanks. I have tried them but it's showing the same errors related to module.
